# npm run watch says errors

Tags: laravel, npm

**Hi all!! Project from github [ecom](https://github.com/webdevmatics/ecom) cloned and installed on my local server,
Project is runing but when i type via cli npm run watch says error like this.**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":true,"ident":"postcss","plugins":[null]}!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"root":"C://xampp//htdocs//ecom//node_modules"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at loadLoader (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:182:3)
    at NormalModule.build (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:275:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:151:10)
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss 4:14-266
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

please help me...

Comment: Try running `npm rebuild node-sass` and compile again

Comment: Try this `npm install css-loader`

Comment: when i run these commands it says like this error  **Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null**

Answer (score 0):

Try this and compile again :

```
npm install node-sass --save
```

Comment: should i add a proxy or http_proxy? maybe a problem i use without any proxy?